# Module not found issue while writing unit test cases for Vue.js front end using mocha web pack

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

> I have two folders in my package called
> components and Docs(Imported some components file from components folder in Docs file).
>
> I can write the unit test cases for components file.
>
> But when I am writing the unit test cases for Docs File, I am facing the errors which mentioned below.

```
Error in ./src/Docs/activityPage.vue  
Module not found: '../components/Button' in '/Volumes/apple/rasool/myProject/src/Docs'
```

Comment: Your comment has a capital C, but your error message has a lower case c. macOS is case sensitive. Are you sure you typed the path name right in your file?

Comment: Yes am sure, I have given correct file path and names in my project